# Insert array of object with in an objects array at specified position javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two array of objects say `var arr1  = [{a:12},{d:14}]` and `var arr2  = [{b:15},{c:10}]` , I want the following result : `arr3 = [{a:12},{b:15},{c:10},{d:14}]`

I want to add objects in arr2 at position 2 of arr1. Note the order of a,b,c,d in arr3.

How to insert an array of objects within another array of objects at specified position like `Array.split()`

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have the position?

Comment: Do you want to `sort` the final array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) with [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for it.

This allows to insert an array into a given array at a certain position.

```js
var arr1  = [{ a: 12 }, { d: 14 }],    
    arr2  = [{ b: 15 }, { c: 10 }];

Array.prototype.splice.apply(arr1, [1, 0].concat(arr2));
console.log(arr1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method with [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method.

```js
var arr1 = [{
    a: 12
  }, {
    d: 14
  }],
  arr2 = [{
    b: 15
  }, {
    c: 10
  }];

// copy array 
var arr3 = arr1.slice();
// insert elements into the array 
// with spread operator
[].splice.apply(arr3, [1, 0, ...arr2]); // where first element in array is the insert position
// or with concat method
// [].splice.apply(arr3, [1, 0].concat(arr2));

console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: concat will append the object at last position of array. I want objects to be added on specified position.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) with [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) spread operator.

```js
var arr1  = [{a:12},{d:14}] 
var arr2  = [{b:15},{c:10}]

arr1.splice(1, 0, ...arr2);
console.log(arr1)
```

If you want to keep original array you can first create copy using `slice()`

```js
var arr1  = [{a:12},{d:14}] 
var arr2  = [{b:15},{c:10}]

var result = arr1.slice(0);
result.splice(1, 0, ...arr2);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know the position, it sounds like you want `array.splice()`.

```
var myFish = ["angel", "clown", "mandarin", "surgeon"];
myFish.splice(2, 0, "drum");
```

Example taken from:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

You can do the exact same thing with objects.

Comment: Yes it does. Nina's answer shows as much.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/40574963/3739551